# get timestamp without reinstantiating the calendar and timestamp

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to get the timestamp.

This works.

```
final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

But, I don't want to reinstantiate the variables each and every time, I need to get the timestamp. How can I do that?

I tried to do..

```
//instantiate the variables.

    private final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
    private final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());

Inside a method()

    // trying to ask calendar to recalculate the time -- not working.
    cal.setTimeZone(tz); // I tried cal.clear() but it is giving me time during 1970 which I don't want.
    ts.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

This doesn't seem to work. Could you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `System.currentTimeMillis()` to avoid creating a calendar.

Comment: So, does System.currentTimeMillis() takes timezone into account as well? I am trying to get CST timezone timestamp.

Comment: No. but neither does your code. Time expressed as milliseconds in java  is all UTC time. To handle timezones you must create a calendar or a date plus a DateFormat instance, and set the timezone appropriately.

Comment: To clarify what I just said, you create a calendar in your code, but then you ask it for milliseconds which will ignore all the timezone stuff and give you miliseconds since the epoch as specified in the calendar javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something, but this:

```
final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);
final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

is equivalent to much more lightweight:

```
final Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

That's because new `GregorianCalendar` with specific time zone points to *now*. And since calling `getTimeInMillis()` "ignores" time zone, you essentially ask for current time in millis since epoch. Which can be done with [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

[`Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class is:

> A thin wrapper around `java.util.Date`

And `Date` represents point in time, irrespective to time zone. You cannot create neither `Timestamp` nor `Date` in arbitrary time zone. These classes do not hold such information. In other words calendar object representing 14:00 in GMT+1 and 13:00 GMT+0 will result in exactly the same `Date` and `Timestamp` objects - because these dates are the same.